# Get average intervals in a list of dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe like this

```
Event   dates                                 Duration
Event1  [1796-12-02, 1796-12-10, 1796-12-11]  9 days
Event2  [1848-03-31, 1848-02-26]              34 days
Event3  [1826-05-20]                          0 days
```

And I would like to add an "Average time inbetween dates" column which would compute the difference between subsequent couple of days and look like:

```
"Average"
4.5
17
0
```

In the first one, 4.5 comes from pair of dates 1: 8 and pair of dates 2: 1, 8+1=9 /2 = 4.5

Comment: If you already know the duration, you can simply do `df["Duration"]/(df["dates"].str.len()-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line:

```
df["Average"] = df.apply(lambda x: float(x["Duration"].replace(" days", ""))/(len(x["dates"])-1), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks how do I make it a float?

Comment: divide by desired `Timedelta` unit, eg `df["Average"]/pd.Timedelta("1d")`

Comment: I have edited the code. You can use replace method on Duration column to convert it to the float type. @myfakeisafakes